# Multiple var check if empty then replace with 0 javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple "input" from HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="m" />
<input type="text" id="m2" />
<input type="text" id="m3" />
<input type="text" id="m4" />
```

and I would like each of these to be checked if empty and then replaced with 0 in javascript I used the following

```
var m1 = document.getElementById('m1').value;
if (m1 === ""){
m1 = 0;
}
```

Is any simple way to check all the input text areas and then replace each empty with 0 value.

Comment: You could give each of the elements the same class and then grab them all at once and loop through them checking if they have empty value and replace with 0, for an example please see my answer below.

Comment: You should consider lib to do it for you if this is not just a simple test crap which you are going to throw away anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="m" class="txtEmptyReplace" />
<input type="text" id="m2" class="txtEmptyReplace" />
<input type="text" id="m3" class="txtEmptyReplace" />
<input type="text" id="m4" class="txtEmptyReplace" />
```

Now that they all have the same class in your js code do something like this:

```
let myTextElements = document.getElementsByClassName("txtEmptyReplace");
for(let x = 0; x < myTextElements.length; x++){
    if(myTextElements[x].value === ""){
       myTextElements[x].value = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll('input')

list.forEach((input) => {
   let val = input.value;
   if (val === ""){
      val = 0;
   }
})
```

Comment: Isn't this supposed to cause some cross-browser issues, older version, IE etc? P.S (w/o the let nonsense, I mean the forEach).

Comment: Correct, NodeList is not supported in IE